# Concurrent Futures in Kivy

Tags: python, concurrency, multiprocessing, kivy

I am trying to add multiprocessing to a GUI. Every kivy GUI design I have seen runs "if name is main" just before starting the app. This conflicts with multiprocessing which uses "if name is main" to organize the processes (im not totally sure how it works, i just know where to put it). Point is, i can't think of a way to run multiprocessing with kivy. I have a code below that does not throw any errors. However, the multiprocessing takes about the same time as without multiprocessing, and occasionally a little less time, when i would expect it to take as long as single run of the function on my cpu with 8 processors. Is there a way to re-write the code so that the typical time save will occur?

```
import concurrent.futures
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
import math
import time


from multiprocessing import Process, Queue, Event

kv = '''
<GUI>:
    Button:
        text: 'press to run calculation'
        on_press: root.do_process()
'''

def func3(numbers):
    c=[]
    for number in numbers:
        c.append(math.sqrt(number ** 5))
    return c

Builder.load_string(kv)


class GUI(BoxLayout):

    def do_process(self):

        var=10000000

        start2=time.time()
        f1=func3(list(range(var)))
        ex3=f1[3]
        f2=func3(list(range(var)))
        ex4=f2[3]
        f3=func3(list(range(var)))
        ex5=f3[3]
        f4=func3(list(range(var)))
        ex6=f4[3]
        f5=func3(list(range(var)))
        ex7=f5[3]
        end2=time.time()


        start3=time.time()
        with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
                #normally "if name is main" goes here when using concurrent futures
                L5=executor.submit(func3,list(range(var)))
                L6=executor.submit(func3,list(range(var)))
                L7=executor.submit(func3,list(range(var)))
                L8=executor.submit(func3,list(range(var)))
                L9=executor.submit(func3,list(range(var)))
               
        ex8 = L5.result()[3]
        ex9=L6.result()[3]
        ex10=L7.result()[3]
        ex11=L8.result()[3]
        ex12=L9.result()[3]
    
        end3=time.time()

        print('time no mp',end2-start2)
        print('time with cf:',end3-start3)


class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return GUI()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

Comment: When I run your code my time with cf is less than half the time with no mp. If you check the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/concurrent.futures.html#processpoolexecutor-example), there is no mention of using an `if` where your comment mentions it.

Comment: Also note that you are comparing running `func3` 5 times with no mp and comparing it to running `func3` 6 time with mp.

Comment: are you trying to solve a real problem or is this just exercise?  I use multiprocessing with Kivy, but I do this in a different way.  I started with Threading and since the interfaces for many objects are the same it is easy to swap over.  I delay importing anything related to Kivy until after the Processes/Threads are created and started.  Even then, Multiprocessing is only barely faster than Threading in my application with Raspberry pi and 4 cores.  There is a lot of overhead exchanging the information between processes.

Comment: to john, if I forget about kivy, and just run concurrent futures with those 5 functions, and don't put if name == 'main': in that commented spot, it gives bootstrapping error. I edited the question to only include func3 five times. it made a difference. it was typically 30 seconds for both, and sometimes 20 seconds for mp. maybe thats the best it will get. to mark, i have a larger code, and was testing out smaller codes first. ive never implemented mp before

Answer (score 1):

I don't have experience with kivy, but for multiprocessing the important feature is that your `__main__` file can be imported without any unintended side effects. Calling all your functional code inside `if __name__ == "__main__":` generally ensures that nothing happens when the file is imported rather than run as the main script, as `__name__` gets bound to something else in that case.

Child processes generally must import the main script to access the target function, which is why this is important. Consider if your main script created two child processes without this protection: those children would `import __main__`, and because `import`ing a file basically just executes the file as normal then binds the global namespace to a variable, each child would create two children of its own, then **boom** [fork bomb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_bomb). Fortunately python detects this and raises an error (the detection happens in the "bootstrapping" phase by disallowing grandchildren from being created until after `import __main__` hence the error name)

If part of your kivy application calls `multiprocessing.Process`, `multiprocessing.Pool`, or `concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor`; **as long as the entry point to the application is protected from execution on import, you should already be protected from the bootstrapping error.**

There are many reasons you might not see the speedup you expect, but in particular I would suspect the overhead of sending the input arguments to the child process and then receiving the results (which all happen in the main process) may be more significant than the work actually being completed in your test function.